# How to initialize value of another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In my app when user redirect to app from browser I am presenting registration page. In that I want to insert value from url variable. So first I am fetching value from url and then displaying that page with  textbox value.But it is not setting textbox value.

my code:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:nil error:nil];
 NSRange r = [urlString rangeOfString:@"gratzeez://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(r.location != NSNotFound){
        NSLog(@"founddddd");
        NSLog(@"gratzeez url %@",url);
        //NSString *str=[url valueForKey:@"email"];
        NSArray *query = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[query count]];
        for(NSString *parameter in query)
        {
            NSArray *kv = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            [parameters setObject:[kv count] > 1 ? [[kv objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] : [NSNull null]
                           forKey:[[kv objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", parameters);


        [self.tabBar dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        RegistrationViewController *RegistrationVC=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];
        RegistrationVC.txtEmail.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        NSLog(@"q = %@", [parameters objectForKey:@"email"]);

        UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:RegistrationVC];
        RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text=[parameters objectForKey:@"email"];
        NSLog(@"value%@",RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text); //here getting null value
        [self.tabBar presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
        navController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
        return YES;

    }
```

what is I present registrationviewcontroller by this way.?

```
RegistrationViewController *RegistrationVC=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] init ];

    NSLog(@"q = %@", [parameters objectForKey:@"email"]);
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:RegistrationVC];

    NSLog(@"txtemail %@ value%@",RegistrationVC.txtEmail,RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text);
    [self.tabBar presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:^{
        RegistrationVC.txtEmail.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text=[parameters objectForKey:@"email"];
    }];
```

Now again this is giving null for both.

Comment: Replace `NSLog(@"value%@",RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text);` with `NSLog(@"textEmail : %@ \nvalue%@",RegistrationVC.txtEmail,RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text);` to check if your textEmail exists at this moment.

Comment: I see you use initWithNibName:bundle, in this case your txtEmail must be placed inside you Nib file, and attached with IBOutlet. I hope your [parameters objectForKey:@"email"] != nil

Comment: @zbMax txtEmail is not present at that time.Now what to do?

Comment: @zbMax  may be this is due to importing appdelegate in registration and registration to appdelegate viewcontroller??

Answer (score 1):

As we've seen in comment, your txtEmail is not created when you try to assign it a value.

I suggest you to add a completion block to the method `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. At this point, your controller `RegistrationVC` will be loaded and its views (and subviews) created, and so you would be able to assign values to your elements :

```
[self.tabBar presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:^{
    RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text=[parameters objectForKey:@"email"];
}];
```

Comment: great...worked...i have done this thing before at that ti e is was working fine...but dont know i have made chages to this and it was not working...anyway thank you...

Comment: If you just instantiate your `RegistrationViewController` with `[[RegistrationViewController alloc] init ]`, you create an controller with a empty view. Every element on the interface builder will not be created. And all IBOutlet will be null. You can see `[[Myclass alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib"]` as `Xcode. Create me an object of type 'Myclass', its view will be the xib named 'myNib'` and associate properties to the element on the interface you've linked to.

Comment: Log txtEmail in the completion block, and not before `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: yes I have set that ...I am getting null in log..and also nothing is set to registrationview page when i am presenting with navigationcontroller.

Comment: If your textEmail is on the interface builder, linked to the .h, and if you create `RegistrationVC` with `[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:nil]`, textEmail should not be null after presenting the view controller... Maybe force to load the view will do the trick... Try to add `[RegistrationVC view]` just after `RegistrationViewController *RegistrationVC=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: it is null may be because I am presenting navigationcontroller.???(initwith:RgistrationViewController)